# Can I control a connected device using Command Prompt?

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, hololens

Basically, I want to be able to control my connected device with the command line as I would control my own PC. Is there a way to do this? My connected device does not have a command line which is why I wish to use Command Prompt on my Windows 10 PC.

For example, I would like to be able to open an app in my device by typing the command to open it in Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to the "Command Prompt" is the Device Portal. 
To enable it, on your HoloLens go to Settings - Update and Security - For Developers - Enable Device Portal.

On your Windows PC you navigate to the IP of your HoloLens and follow the steps. 
The device portal gives you access to a lot of functionality including installing, removing, starting and stopping apps.

[Here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/using_the_windows_device_portal) is the full documentation on Device Portal.

There is also a [REST API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/device_portal_api_reference) that you can use to code your own version of the device portal.